# Getting X items from two models ordered by date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Imagine I have two models:

foo and bar.

I have a page where I show X items (paginating with kaminari).

Those items would be a combination of foo and bar.

So I need to retrieve an array of X items ordered by created_at.

Imagine that foo have 25 items and bar just 10.

I ask for 10 items, and I need the first 10 items ordered by created_at. Maybe there are 7 foo and 3 bar mixed in.

I know that I can retrieve and merge them, but the problem is that if I request 10 foo and 10 bar, order by date and get the first 10. If I ask for page two, I will be losing items.

Maybe I'm asking too much, but would be good ask for a page 1, retrieve 10 items of foo/bar mix, ask for page 2, and same stuff. Maybe I need a third table?

Ideas? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a view that is the combination of the two tables. Then query for the top 10 records in that table. Check out this gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/rails_sql_views.

If these are similar concepts, you could actually use one table and two models with single table inheritance.

Comment: One model is a Post and the other is just like a twitt, just a message less than 140-150 characters. Inheritance doesn't seems to fit.